# Add paging buttons to gridview pagersetting set to Numeric

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I'd like to implement paging on my gridview control. I'd like it to look like this

`First Previous 12345...Next Last`

Unfortunately, asp.net's gridview doesn't support this. It only supports `NextPrevious`, `Numeric`, `NextPreviousFirstLast` and `NumericFirstLast`.

Rather than creating my own custom pager, I'd like to use the `Numeric` mode and just add the buttons for First, Previous, Next and Last. How do I put the buttons side by side with the numeric values if the pager is generated by asp on runtime?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `PagerSettings PageButtonCount` property of the Gridview.

Here is en example:

```
 <PagerSettings 
Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
PageButtonCount="5" 
PreviousPageText="Previous" 
NextPageText="Next" 
FirstPageText="First" 
LastPageText="Last" />
```